# Error: "DLL is already started"

Tags: c#, c++, dll, native, event-viewer

I have c# code and using c++ dll.

When I start my application, It always give error in event viewer

> Error: "ABC.dll is already started."

Comment: Could you post the code that is giving you the error?

Comment: I don't know from where that error is coming from source. This error is in event viewer.

Comment: Then it sounds like what it says it is.  This `DLL` is already running somewhere, in some service and you are trying to launch it again.  Have you rebooted, looked in your task manager and shut down all your start up processes?

Comment: does it really say *ABC* or is it something else?

Comment: @paqogomez: I have rebooted my system. Error is still there. It doesn't help :(

Comment: @stijn: I have just mentioned ABC It have a specific name related to my app.

Comment: Searching the internet doesn't seem to give any search results for the "is already started" string which indicates it's in your code. So have a better look at it and figure out where it originates. Also run your application under the debugger and go through it step by step so you can see at what point exactly the message occurs.

Comment: My application is not getting started because of that error. I can't debug and I have searched in source code didn't find it.

Comment: @stijn's point is that you are not giving us any information that we can deduce your problem.

Comment: Without more information, I have a feeling that the DLL checks at startup whether it's been loaded already, writes the message to the event viewer, and returns a failure code on load.

Comment: from where I can stop that DLL ?